# PowerShell concatenate output of Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

I have a working script that searches for files with a regular expression. The script returns 2 lines per file: the parent folder naùe, and the filename (matching the regex).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\test\" -Recurse -File |
  Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^[0-9]+$' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -Split '\',-3,'SimpleMatch' } | 
     select -last 2 | 
       Out-File "D:\wim.txt"
```

A certain system needs to have the output on one line, concatenated with for example \ or a similar character. How can I achieve this please ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Enclose the whole command except the out-file in parentheses, append a `(...) -join '\'| Out-File "D:\wim.txt"`

Comment: Thanks, I will test tomorrow since it’s very late here. I didn’t expect such a quick answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\test -Recurse -File | 
  Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^[0-9]+$' } | 
    ForEach-Object { ($_.FullName -split '\\')[-2,-1] -join '\' } |                          #'
      Out-File D:\wim.txt
```

- `($_.FullName -Split '\\')[-2,-1]` extracts the last 2 components from the file path
- and `-join '\'` joins them back together.

---

Note that, aside from the line-formatting issue, **your original command does *not* work as intended, because `| select -last 2` is applied to the *overall* output**, not *per matching file*; thus, even if there are *multiple* matching files, you'll only ever get the parent directory and filename of the *last* matching file.

The command above therefore extracts the last 2 `\`-separated path components *inside the `ForEach-Object` block*, directly on the result of the `-split` operation, so that 2 (joined) components are returned *per file*.

As an aside, the `-3` in `$_.FullName -split '\', -3, 'SimpleMatch'` does *not* extract the last 3 tokens; it is currently effectively treated the same as `0`, meaning that *all* resulting tokens are returned; given that `-split` defaults to using *regexes*, and representing a literal `\` requires escaping as `\\`, `$_.FullName -split '\', -3, 'SimpleMatch'` is the same as `$_.FullName -split '\\'`, which is what the solution above uses.

Note that there is a [green-lit `-split` enhancement](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4765) that will give negative [`<Max-substrings>` values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) new meaning in the future, applying the current positive-number logic analogously to the *end* of the input string; e.g, `-3` would mean: return the last 2 components plus whatever is left of the input string before them (with the resulting tokens still reported from left to right).