# Filenames matching regex but in folder with wildcard

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

This is a follow up question of: [PowerShell concatenate output of Get-ChildItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473417/powershell-concatenate-output-of-get-childitem)

This code works fine:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter "*.vue" -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^[0-9]+$' } |
    ForEach-Object { ($_.FullName -split '\\')[-2,-1] -join '\' } |
    Out-File D:\wim.txt
```

But I would need to restrict the search folder to only certain folders, basically, this filter: `D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes\\*}vues` (so all subfolders ending in `}vues`).

If I add that wildcard condition I get no result. Without the restriction, I get the correct result. Is this possible please?

[image: without filter]

[image: with filter]

The idea is to get rid of the 3rd line in the first output (which was a copy/paste by me) and also to minimize the number of folders to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *nest* two `Get-ChildItem` calls:

- An outer `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse` call to filter *directories* of interest first,
- an inner `Get-ChildItem -File` call that, for each directory found, examines and processes the *files* of interest.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter "*}vues" -Recurse -Directory |
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Filter "*.vue" -File | 
      Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^[0-9]+$' } | 
        ForEach-Object { ($_.FullName -split '\\')[-2,-1] -join '\' }                 
  } | Out-File D:\wim.txt
```

Note: The assumption is that all `*.vue` files of interest are located *directly* in each `*}vues` folder.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Given that you're limiting items being enumerated to *files* (`-File`),  your directory-name wildcard pattern `*}vues` never gets to match any *directory* names and, in the absence of *files* matching that pattern, returns *nothing*.

Generally, with `-Recurse` it is conceptually cleaner *not* to append the wildcard pattern directly to the `-Path` argument, so as to better signal that the pattern will be matched in *every* directory in the subtree.

In your case you would have noticed your attempt to filter *doubly*, given that you're *also* using the `-Filter` parameter.

Comment: Bingo ! Great work. And I should have spotted that one myself.

Comment: @W.Gielis: Thanks; no worries; I'm glad we got there.